# Can local notification triggered on iOS from macOS?

Tags: ios, macos

I want to trigger local notification on Iphone from mac.
Is this possible using Handoff Api or any other api (e.g Bluetooth or any other). If not please let me know any alternative way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have used the BLE to trigger notification. MacOs act as peripherals and IOS act as master device. I have used https://github.com/noble/bleno on macOs side and default Bluetooth Kit on IOS side. I have tried to use Bonjour and Socket IO but they do not support background process.